# GCC atomic shared_ptr implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, shared-ptr, stdatomic

According to **https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57250**, GCC 4.9 has support for atomic `shared_ptr` operations.

Using GCC 4.9.2, I'm able to compile a program that uses atomic `shared_ptr`.  The `-mcx16` flag is required, as the GCC implementation on x86_64 apparently requires `cmpxchg16b`, which makes sense as I would assume that an atomic operation on a `shared_ptr` would require atomically updating both the pointer itself and the reference count at the same time.

However, when I try to actually *use* the atomic `shared_ptr` library, it does not behave as I expect.  So, either I am not using this properly, or the GCC implementation is defective.  Most of the time I'd be 99% confident that I'm just doing it wrong, but since this is a relatively new feature and since the behavior seems so bizarre, I'm only about 50% confident that it's my fault in this case.

Here is a simple program that creates an atomic `shared_ptr`, then performs a series of concurrent reads and writes on the shared_ptr:

```
void test()
{
        std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<int>> p(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(10)));

        std::cout << "Use count : " << p.load().use_count() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Initial value of p : " << *(p.load()) << std::endl;

        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        const std::size_t num_threads = 8;

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i != num_threads; ++i)
        {
                threads.emplace_back([&p, i](){

                        std::shared_ptr<int> x = p.load();
                        while (!p.compare_exchange_weak(
                                x,
                                std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(i + 5))
                        )) ;
                });
        }

        for (auto& t : threads) t.join();

        std::cout << "Use count : " << p.load().use_count() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Final value of p : " << *(p.load()) << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile and run, the output is:

```
~$ g++ test2.cpp -o test2 -std=c++11 -lpthread -mcx16
~$ ./test2
Use count : 1
Initial value of p : 0
Use count : 0
Final value of p : 0
```

But this output makes no sense to me.  Firstly, after initializing the atomic `shared_ptr` to a value of `10`, when I load it and read the initial value (before any threads are spawned), I get a `0`.  Secondly, after all the threads join, the value is still `0`, even though no thread could have possibly set it to `0`.  And most bizarrely, after the threads join, the `use_count()` of the shared_ptr is `0`! Yet the atomic `shared_ptr` object is still in scope, and thus the use count should be `1`.

I'm pretty sure the GCC implementation is flawed here, but according to the link I posted above, GCC 4.9 has a completed atomic `shared_ptr` implementation, and...

```
~$ gcc --version
~$ gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
```

So... what exactly is going on here?  I'd like to get some kind of confirmation that either the GCC 4.9.2 implementation here is flawed or incomplete, or I'm just totally wrong/confused about how to use atomic `shared_ptr`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems maybe the latter? On the reference page for the std::atomic page, it does not mention specializations for shared_ptr: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic. Indeed, when I try to compile your code, I trigger a static assert: error: static assertion failed: std::atomic requires a trivially copyable type. So it seems like this is incorrect usage, and the code was not hardened against it in older compiler versions, leading to some strange behavior.

Comment: That's a bug report *against* GCC 4.9, fixed in 5.

Comment: Are you confusing atomic with lock-free by any chance?

Comment: "_would require atomically updating both the pointer itself and the reference count at the same time_" In general a modification to one `shared_ptr` involves two ref counts and one ptr. And they are in different memory allocations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"atomic `shared_ptr` operations" refers to the free `std::atomic_(store|load|exchange|compare_exchange_strong|compare_exchange_weak)(_explicit)?` function templates for `shared_ptr`, documented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic). GCC doesn't have them until 5. (Fun fact: its implementation actually uses a global array of 16 mutexes under the hood.)

Instantiating `std::atomic` over `std::shared_ptr` results in undefined behavior, as `std::atomic` requires a trivially copyable type.

The concurrency TS has `std::experimental::atomic_shared_ptr`.